# How activate href link in ArcGIS API?

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, popup, dojo, hyperlink

I have some problems with opening a link in ArcGIS API. I have my popup window where LAT, LONG and LINK are shown.

```
function addPoint(evt) {
        var latitude = evt.mapPoint.getLatitude();
        var longitude = evt.mapPoint.getLongitude();
        var link = "<a href='http://www.google.com'>Google</a>";
        map.infoWindow.setTitle("Coordinates");
        map.infoWindow.setContent(
        "lat: " + latitude.toFixed(7) + "<br> lon: " + longitude.toFixed(7) + "<br> Room: " + link
        );
        map.infoWindow.show(evt.mapPoint, map.getInfoWindowAnchor(evt.screenPoint));

}
```

Here is the image [image: example]
However when I click on the link nothing happens (no redirection or opening in new window).
I tried to add window.open() to open the link,

```
var link = "<a href='http://www.google.com'>Google Office</a>";
        on(link, 'click', openLink);
        function openLink(){
            window.open("http://www.google.com");
        }
```

but then I get the error message

> Uncaught Error: Target must be an event emitter

Answer (score 1):

i couldn't reproduce the behavior you describe in my own application (see example [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/59331579/js/popup-href.html)), but i did see problems in a [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/qigiba/3/edit) until i added `target='_blank'` to force the new page to open in a new tab so maybe you're running into something similar in your own application.

```
"<a target='_blank' href='http://www.esri.com'>link</a>"
```

(working jsbin example [here](http://jsbin.com/qigiba/2/edit?html,output))